# Machine learning: working with array of objects in preprocessing

Tags: python, dictionary, machine-learning, data-preprocessing

We have been facing a problem in preprocessing for our project that some columns contain an array of objects ( dictionaries ) like that

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| movie1 | [{"iso_639_1": "en", "name": "English"}, {"iso_639_1": "zh", "name": "\u666e\u901a\u8bdd"}] |
| movie2 | [{"iso_639_1": "da", "name": "Dansk"}, {"iso_639_1": "en", "name": "English"}, {"iso_639_1": "no", "name": "Norsk"}, {"iso_639_1": "ru", "name": "P\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439"}] |

so it might be helpful to suggest us an idea to solve this problem

got no idea of working with problems like that

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# optional: apply literal_eval if values in "Column B" are strings
#df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].apply(literal_eval)

df = df.explode('Column B')
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('Column B').apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Column A iso_639_1     name
0   movie1        en  English
0   movie1        zh      普通话
1   movie2        da    Dansk
1   movie2        en  English
1   movie2        no    Norsk
1   movie2        ru  Pусский
```